# How to prevent 2 Os in Different Drives to mess with the boot sectors of the Other

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

In the past I had a PC with Dual boot in 2 different physical drives, to easily switch between OS with the Bios menu.

- HDD1 Windows
- HDD2 Ubuntu

But when one of the 2 Os get an update always messes with the boot sector of the other

**For example**

Ubuntu installed in HDD2 Its upgraded and install a new version of GRUB in both of the drives making the prompt of Grub apear in the Windows installation and the Ubuntu.

How I tell to Ubuntu or Windows to work only in one Drive?

Comment: By choosing one to handle booting.

Comment: It shouldn't install a new version of GRUB in both of the drives. Also why do you have two GRUBs? Are you chainloading?

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @TinNguyen I didn't installed a new version of GRUB Manually, my problem was, and I repeat my case.
2 drives, one fully dedicated to Windows and the Other fully dedicated to Ubuntu,

when I installed Ubuntu I selected to Install the file system and GRUB in the second disc, all worked Great, but in the first major update of Ubuntu, Ubuntu Automaticly Installed grub in both of the dives. and when I select the windows Disk in the bios to boot windows It appears the GRUB menu with options for windows and Ubuntu, the same in the Ubuntu disk

my question is, how I make sure to this not happen?

Comment: When you update your Ubuntu it shouldn't have an effect on your Windows OS. I suspect you have Windows partitions mounted on your Ubuntu which is fine if it was a share partition but not when it is the OS partition.